# Ошибка версий при установке tf-nightly

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip, tensorflow

Не работает пакет Keras, прочитал, что нужно установить tf-nightly, при установке через `pip install tf-nightly` выдаёт следующее:

```
ERROR: pip's dependency resolver does not currently take into account all the packages that are 
installed. This behaviour is the source of the following dependency conflicts.

tf-nightly 2.6.0.dev20210331 requires gast==0.4.0, but you have gast 0.3.3 which is incompatible.

tf-nightly 2.6.0.dev20210331 requires grpcio~=1.34.0, but you have grpcio 1.32.0 which is 
incompatible.

tf-nightly 2.6.0.dev20210331 requires h5py~=3.1.0, but you have h5py 2.10.0 which is incompatible.

Successfully installed gast-0.3.3 grpcio-1.32.0 h5py-2.10.0
```

Следующие действия, в которых возможно содержится моя ошибка, не помогли:

```
pip unintall gast
pip uninstall grpcio
pip uninstall h5py
pip install gast==0.3.3
pip install grpcio==1.32.0
pip install h5py==2.10.0
pip install tf-nightly
```

после выполнения выскакивает всё та же ошибка, причём в момент, когда я  отдельно устанавливаю пакеты определенной версии выскакивает ошибка

```
ERROR: pip's dependency resolver does not currently take into account all the packages that are 
installed. This behaviour is the source of the following dependency conflicts.
tf-nightly 2.6.0.dev20210331 requires gast==0.4.0, which is not installed.
tf-nightly 2.6.0.dev20210331 requires grpcio~=1.34.0, which is not installed.
tensorflow 2.4.1 requires gast==0.3.3, which is not installed.
tensorflow 2.4.1 requires grpcio~=1.32.0, which is not installed.
tf-nightly 2.6.0.dev20210331 requires h5py~=3.1.0, but you have h5py 2.10.0 which is incompatible.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Была таже проблема. Ушла когда поставил python 3.6.8 x64. [Вот отсюда качай установщик.](https://www.python.org/downloads/windows/)
Ставь галочку PATCH.